Open device in non-exclusive mode using node-hid
I am using node-hid to access gamepad controllers in electron app. I am trying to use node-hid to open the device. But I need non-exclusive access to the device across platforms.
From my limited understanding, I am gathering that the underlying libusb/hidapi does support non-exclusive access across at least windows and mac, but I don't see how to do this with node-hid.
Final goal: To open the gamepad using node-hid (or similar node package) in a non exclusive fashion so that the gamepad is still available for the user to play a game with a completely different software.
